# how implement aws redshift in nodejs project?

Tags: aws-sdk-js

what are the params used for send using this package '@aws-sdk/client-redshift'

```js
const { RedshiftClient, AcceptReservedNodeExchangeCommand } = require("@aws-sdk/client-redshift");
const client = new RedshiftClient({ region: "REGION" });

const params = {
  /** input parameters */ 
};
const command = new AcceptReservedNodeExchangeCommand(params);
```

Answer (score 3):

params is type: AcceptReservedNodeExchangeCommand. It is defined here: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaScriptSDK/v3/latest/clients/client-redshift/interfaces/acceptreservednodeexchangecommandinput.html

Is has two parameters:
{ ReservedNodeId: string, TargetReservedNodeOfferingId: string}

Hint 1: If you want to query Redshift database, you can do it like this:

```
const awsRedshiftClient = new RedshiftDataClient({region: REGION});

const executeStatementCommand = new ExecuteStatementCommand({
    ClusterIdentifier: 'redshift-cluster',
    Database: database,
    DbUser: user,
    Sql: QUERY
});

const executeStatementResult = await awsRedshiftClient.send(executeStatementCommand);
console.log(`Statement id: ${executeStatementResult.Id}`);  

//wait - just to test
await new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(resolve, 5000));

//to get result
const command = new DescribeStatementCommand({Id: executeStatementResult.Id});
const result = await awsRedshiftClient.send(command);
```

Hint 2:

```
Use https://node-postgres.com/ to access Redshift
```

Comment: Thanks this helped me a lot but can you tell it is possible to make this work without await new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(resolve, 5000));.